# Javascript - How to enable/disable text input in IE9

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-9

The following script worked in IE8 but not in IE9:

```
function toggleSelect(fieldName)
{
    var idx = fieldName.lastIndexOf("_");
    var sub = fieldName.substring(19,idx);
    if (document.findForm["cb_Row_PageAutoDelete_" + sub].checked) {
          document.findForm["SHIP_QTY_" + sub].disabled=false ;
    } else {
        document.findForm["SHIP_QTY_" + sub].disabled=true ;
    }
    return true;
}
```

I can display the value of the SHIP_QTY field so I know it's on the page but the disable function does not work.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: *"The following script worked in IE8 but not in IE9"* Worked **how**? What do you expect to have happen? What happens instead? Are you expecting disabling the form to disable all of the input elements within it?

Comment: These are event functions, I'd look at finding ways to work from the newest browers back to legacy versions.

Answer (score 0):

If `findForm` is the name of the form, you want `window.findForm` rather than `document.findForm`. You can also just use the result of the other field's `checked` property directly rather than an `if/else`. So your code changes to:

```
function toggleSelect(fieldName)
{
    var idx = fieldName.lastIndexOf("_");
    var sub = fieldName.substring(19,idx);
    window.findForm["SHIP_QTY_" + sub].disabled = window.findForm["cb_Row_PageAutoDelete_" + sub].checked;
    return true;
}
```

Comment: findForm is the name of the form.  The user is presented with a number of records in a table format, when the checkbox on a line is checked, another input on the line needs to become editable and vice versa.  Can't get the enable/disable to work in IE9.

Comment: @user1352335: *"findForm is the name of the form"* Ah, then you want `window.findForm`, not `document.findForm`.

Comment: @user1352335: *"findForm is the name of the form"* Ah, then you want `window.findForm`, not `document.findForm`. Also, somehow I'd gotten the idea you wanted to disable all the controls within the form, but reading your question now I think you just want to disable the one field. I've updated the answer.